# Defaults for username and password

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've noticed on some locations for auth libraries people have set up private variables called

```
private $username = 'testuser';
private $password = 'testpassword';
```

I don't understand what the use would be for setting up these variables if you'll never use these defaults. Can I get some explanation for why someone would assign these with test values?

Comment: For mocking stuff in tests, possibly.

Comment: Haha thx Kevin & moonwave you made my day :))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are only used for tests, IE: to show where that information is.

Comment: Oh so for a development level only.